# How to determine if Windows application was started automatically on Windows startup?

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there a way for a native Windows application to find out wether it was started automatically on Windows startup or it was started manually by the user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the startup shortcut pass a commandline flag.